# How to create ViewPager tabs in Android (modern way)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I sucessfully created my first ViewPager slider. When I went to the creation of the tabs, I've found that [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) iws deprecated. I also found that I can use PagerTitleStrip, which worked but its too ugly. I've found a library for customizing it but I needed to learn how to do it the hard way, because I want to understand how Android works. Could somebody help me understanding how it works?

Comment: Check out this : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

       private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new About(),"Article 1");
            adapter.addFragment(new About(),"Article 2");
            adapter.addFragment(new About(),"Article 3");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
           }
```

Refer here:https://coderzpassion.com/working-appbarlayout-like-whatsapp/

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a guide](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#) on Google's suggested usage of tabs in Material Design.

In particular, the [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) class from the support design libraries might be what you're after.

Its defaults are very natural, like shown below (taken from the Material Design link above).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-
Add the **PageTabStrip** element as a child of your ViewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_toolbar">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab"
        style="@style/AppToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Make sure you implement the below method in your Custom Adapter extending FragmentPagerAdapter :

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return "Title 1";
        case 1:
            return "Title 2";
        default:
            return "null";
    }

}
```